# What is the difference of a physician specializing in cytology and a physician specializing in medical genetics?

Tags: cancer, genetics, genetic-predisposition

Is cell biology much broader than just genetics or am I conjecturing nonsense? Who is the specialist in the molecular biology of cancer? I am a cancer patient since 16, a medical student aiming for radiation(not classical i.e pathologic) oncology and subsidiary MSc&Phd in radiophysics. I am actually autistic but with no mental retardation. So I need the questions to help me explain myself, why some events seem paradoxical and exactly what information I need. I extensively and thoroughly read ncbi, pubmed and textbooks concerned with my question in hand. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11173079

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Only the third question can easily be answered: specialist for the molecular biology of cancer. Probably either oncology, radiation oncology, or a subspecialty of pathology.  Geneticists aren't always physicians, but physicians who do genetics can come from different specialties.

Comment: @DoctorWhom In Greece there is a specific Medical Speciality( a Residence) in Medical Genetics duration of residence teaching and training 5 years [ of which 1 Year in Pediatrics 3 years in Clinical Dysmorphology(You can specialise in Pathologic Oncology) 6 months in cytogenetics and 6 months in molecular genetis] and one in Cytology 5 years of duration[ of which 2 years in anatomopathology and 3 years in cytology]. I study radiation oncology and we do not study much molecular biology and chemistry. Certainly a Cytologist or a Medical Geneticist specializes in the molecular biology of cancerct

Comment: @DoctorWhom ctd Now I am looking into molucural biology of cancer as subsidiary to radiation oncology so I am looking for a second residence. Cytology or Medical Genetics as far as molecular biology of cancer goes?

Comment: Ah I apologize, I cannot answer that, the system is different in the USA.  That is not a subspecialty that I was aware of.  You might suggest contacting individuals who study what you want to study and ask them what they recommend for your training.  You would be surprised how even relatively famous people might enthusiastically respond when asked such questions.  Perhaps the chair of the rad onc department at your medical institution's hospital.

Comment: Are there no Cytology or Medical genetics in USA?

Comment: Athens, Greece, e.g. http://www.ssiem.org/nationalsocieties/membercountriesdetails.asp?cid=29 ; Medical Genetics, Hellas https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/mgg3.179 Maybe some of these individuals can answer your questions.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Actually Cytology here is named Cytopathology in USA. Is there a distinct speciality(medical residence) named Cytopathology? Is there a distinct speciality named Medical Genetics?

Comment: I was not aware, but apparently yes they are subspecialties.  See here for list of specialties in the USA: https://www.aamc.org/cim/specialty/exploreoptions/list/